# find the limit $\lim \limits_{x \to {\pi/2}} \frac {\sin x -(\sin x)^{\sin x}} {1-\sin x+\log (\sin x)}$

Tags: limits

> $\displaystyle \lim\limits_{x \to {\pi/2}} \frac {\sin x -(\sin x)^{\sin x}} {1-\sin x+\log (\sin x)}$
>
> **Solution** :
>
> We can solve this question by L' Hospital rule
>
> But it will be a bit tedious

Is there any other easy method to solve this question ??

Comment: Yes, Taylor expansion in general. But in this case see below.

Comment: Since this is purely a function of $\sin x$, you can replace it with $$\lim_{y \to 1^-} \frac{y - y^y}{1 - y + \log y}.$$

Comment: @ErickWong thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set $y=\sin x$.  Then you have $$\lim_{y\rightarrow 1}\frac{y-y^y}{1-y+\ln y}=\left(\lim_{y\rightarrow 1}y\right) \left(\lim_{y\rightarrow 1}\frac{1-y^{y-1}}{1-y+\ln y}\right)$$

This is now an easier L'Hopital's rule application.

Comment: Very nice observation (+1)

Comment: Yeah ,it will be easier